# What is meant by uniform distribution of hash values in Hashing technique

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashtable

In **Hashing**, what does this **uniform distribution of hash values** mean. **Please explain in layman's terms using appropriate example.**

Comment: What is this, an assignment question? Check wiki page for hashing...you will get your answer.

Comment: i did, but wasn't able to figure it out

Comment: @NavneetSrivastava This is an easily researchable question, and the answer you will find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Properties) is far clearer and coherent than the answer you've accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that if you have some size of your hash-table (Say `n`), then if you are hashing `k` values `k<n`, then:

> A sequence of outputs from the function must appear to be a random sequence, even if the input numbers are sequential

Also, fundamental thing for your hash function should be to minimize collisions obviously, but at the same time, for a skewed input, output from hash-function should be distributed.

EDIT:

As asked, here is what uniform distribution means. Say, if your size of hash-table is `n` and you push `k (<n)` elements to it, then, in every bucket of `n/k` in hash table, there should be an element. Also, if `k=r*c`, in every bucket of size `n/c` in hash table, there should be `r` elements.

Obviously, perfect uniform distribution is not possible...but output distribution should not be skewed.

Comment: what does your last line mean @vish4071

Comment: @Bergi could you explain this in simple terms, I am new to computers

Comment: @NavneetSrivastava: Are you new to maths as well? You do know what a [distribution](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_distribution) is, right?

Comment: The last line is exactly the answer. The quoted text is just the explanation.

Comment: @vish4071 thnx my doubt has been cleared, thnx a lot

Comment: @Bergi thnx for the link